# Несколько целей для phantom

Tags: яндекс-танк

Добрый день. Пытаюсь сделать тест с несколькими инстансами phantom, опираясь на [эту документацию](http://yandextank.readthedocs.io/en/stable/core_and_modules.html#multi-tests). Для разных инстансов использую разные адреса и разные файлы патронов (в них разные теги, запросы одни и те же).

Я пробовал несколько вариантов, если не указывать адрес в общей секции [phantom], то при запуске начинается обстрел 127.0.0.1, если не указывать в ней ammofile, то при запуске выдается ошибка что не хватает патронов. А если сделать в общей секции конфигурацию для обстрела первого хоста, а в [phantom-1] - второго, то обстреливается только первый. Скажите, что я делаю не так?

Конфиг с третьим вариантом:
    [tank]
    plugin_uploader=yandextank.plugins.DataUploader overload

```
[overload]
token_file=token.txt
job_name=mytest

[phantom]
rps_schedule=step(50,700,50, 300s)
header_http = 1.1
ammo_type=uri
address = 172.28.XX.XX
ammofile=first.ammo.gz

[phantom-1]
address = 172.28.XX.YY
rps_schedule=step(50,700,50, 300s) 
header_http = 1.1
ammofile=second.ammo.gz
ammo_type=uri
```

Comment: Секции фантома независимые, общих нет  (это неочевидно, но это так).

Comment: Вы уверены что с приведенным вариантом нагрузка не подается в два хоста? Выглядит ок

Comment: https://pastebin.com/UCcPst9i - пример с похожим конфигом и проверкой tcpdump-ом что нагрузка идет в два хоста